# Event Handling with MSTest Async/Await Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, mstest, async-await

I'm writing unit tests using VS2012 for a class that uses async/await pattern on a method.  The class also has events which I want to write to the TestContext so they are visible in the test output.  The problem I find is that the event handler method in my test class is not called.  The test passes but the event handler responsible for TestContext.WriteLine is not called.  Here is the code.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Organize_Copy_No_Search_Pattern_Specified()
{
    string result = null;

    ClassToTest _classToTest = new ClassToTest(sourceFolder, destFolder);
    _classToTest.OrganizerResult += _classToTest_Result;

    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

    result = await _classToTest._RunMethodAsync(cancellationToken);

    int areSame = String.Compare(SuccessMsg, result, true);

    Assert.AreEqual(0, areSame); // Passes

}

// This event handler never gets called?
void _classToTest_Result(string syncMessage)
{
    string msg = syncMessage;
    TestContext.WriteLine(msg);
}

private TestContext testContextInstance;
public TestContext TestContext
{
    get
    {
        return testContextInstance;
    }
    set
    {
        testContextInstance = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to me the problem is in `ClassToTest`.

Comment: Interesting I'll double check it.  However, I know it works because I actually have it running in Windows form application and all the output is displayed.  This seems unique to the MSTest which is why I posted.